# SourceTree, Error Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm getting below error while cloning a repo through Sourcetree.

[image]

I'm able to login directly through bitbucket.org but not through Sourcetree. Let me know how this issue needs to be fixed.

SourceTree version: 3.3.9

TIA

Answer (score 65):

Let's try this:

1. Tools -> Options -> Authentication
2. Click "Edit" on Your Account
3. Click "Refresh OAuth Token"

It works for me :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It happened to me when I connected to another network.

Comment: This didn't work until after I deleted the two year old github entry in Windows Credential Manager. Then it worked like, well, not a charm, better than those.

Comment: this didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 4):

I found out that the reason why SourceTree cannot authorize our GitHub account is that source tree is using the old git version so that it doesn't authorize our account through web but through its own application which is not permitted by Git.
[Git Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1X5B.png)

Solution:
First of all, you must know where your SourceTree stores your local datas (which is also the local git). You go to Tools > Options. Choose Git tab, and then choose Embeded in Git version which will tell you the path to their local datas. Mine is "C:\Users\as\AppData\Local\Atlassian".
[Git Local path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEfTz.png)

And then you need to delete all the folder in the Atlassian and then uninstall SourceTree.
After all, you install new version of Git from this: https://gitforwindows.org/ and install new SourceTree from this: https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

And then you just need to open your repository from the Add button, and try to push again.
[SourceTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZeVU.png)

They will appear the web-authorization for you to sign in. And after all that, it works.
[Git Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GYBI.png)

Comment: Just as a FYI, no need to re install sourceTree after pressing "Update Embedded" button. Worked like a charm! Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Authenticate with OAuth instead of Basic.

Answer (score 2):

Tools/Options/Authentication, delete your github account, add again. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Tools> Options> Authentication> Edit already existing account - Enter password and save again. This might refresh your password in your SourceTree

Answer (score 1):

This is still relevant!

I solve it by updating SourceeTree.

0. Remove Sourcetree from PC
1. Download the new version from the official site: [click](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)
2. After open, on the top right corner press the yellow flag to update, then click "restart".
3. Go to Tools => Settings => GIT => Update Embedded.

For version 3.4.0 I have Embedded v2.29.2.

Then press Fetch, for example. Select "Use no helper" in a popup window. Also, check "don't ask again". Enter email/login and password into the login popup.

Success for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue.  I opened the project in Visual Studio 2019 and attempted the same request as before.  This prompted me for the same username and password, but also allowed me to authorize using the website.  I selected this and was able to go back into SourceTree and continue the clone.